# Threadsafe Non-Overlapping Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net, thread-safety, timer

I was working on a project recently, where I needed to process some tasks periodically, but the execution of those tasks could not overlap with one another. `System.Threading.Timer` is definitely the best choice for this, but it does not prevent callbacks from overlapping. Realizing this, I wrote my own, aptly named `NonOverlappingTimer`, which uses a combination of locking and modification of callback execution intervals to avoid overlaps. Below is my implementation.

**NonOverlappingTimer**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

/// <summary>
/// A threadsafe timer that wraps a <see cref="System.Threading.Timer"/> and
/// provides a mechanism for executing <see cref="Action"/>s 
/// on a thread pool thread at a specified interval.
/// </summary>  
internal sealed class NonOverlappingTimer : IDisposable
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private int _interval = 0;
    private Action _callBack;
    private readonly int _timeout = 0;
    private readonly object _threadLock = new object();
    private long _disposedCount = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="NonOverlappingTimer"/> class with 
    /// the interval (in terms of milliseconds) at which the 
    /// callback method is invoked, as well as an infinite timeout for the dispose method. 
    /// </summary>  
    /// <remarks>
    /// It is recommended that the callback method support cancellation to avoid the dispose
    /// method potentially waiting for an infinite amount of time. 
    /// </remarks>
    public NonOverlappingTimer(int interval, Action callBack) : this(interval, callBack, Timeout.Infinite)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="NonOverlappingTimer"/> class with 
    /// the interval (in terms of milliseconds) at which the 
    /// callBack method is invoked, as well as the timeout (in terms of milliseconds) 
    /// that the dispose method will wait for the running callBack to complete. 
    /// </summary>  
    /// <remarks>
    /// If the timeout is exceeded then a <see cref="TimeoutException"/> will be 
    /// thrown. It is recommended that the callback method support cancellation to 
    /// avoid the dispose method potentially waiting for a period exceeding the 
    /// timeout. 
    /// </remarks>
    public NonOverlappingTimer(int interval, Action callBack, int timeout)
    {
        if (interval < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(interval));
        }

        _interval = interval;
        _callBack = callBack;
        _timeout = timeout;

        // This constructor specifies an infinite due time before the first callback
        // and an infinite interval between callbacks, preventing the timer from
        // firing until NonOverlappingTimer.Start() is called.
        _timer = new Timer(OnTimerElaspsed, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the timer.
    /// </summary>  
    /// <remarks>
    /// The callback will not be invoked until the interval specified 
    /// in the constructor has elapsed. 
    /// </remarks>
    public void Start()
    {
        _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        Reset();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the timer.
    /// </summary>  
    /// <remarks>
    /// Since the callback method specified for a <see cref="System.Threading.Timer"/>  
    /// runs on the <see cref="ThreadPool"/>, it is possible for the timer to elapse
    /// after this method is called (i.e. a race condition). This is why the
    /// callback method specified should be reentrant.
    /// </remarks>
    public void Stop()
    {
        _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resets the timer to run in now + interval specified in the constructor.
    /// </summary> 
    /// <remarks>
    /// This may not take effect immediately, because the callback method 
    /// could be running when this method is called. 
    /// </remarks>
    public void Reset()
    {
        _timer.Change(_interval, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Changes the timer to run in now + interval.
    /// </summary> 
    /// <remarks>
    /// The may not take effect imediately, because the callback method 
    /// could be running when it is called. 
    /// </remarks>
    public void Change(int interval)
    {
        if (interval < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(interval));
        }

        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _interval, interval); 

        _timer.Change(interval, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes of the underlying <see cref="Timer"/>. 
    /// </summary>  
    /// <remarks>
    /// Since the callback method specified for a <see cref="Timer"/>  
    /// runs on the <see cref="ThreadPool"/>, it is possible for the timer to elapse
    /// after this method is called (i.e. a race condition). This method
    /// waits for the queued callback to finish before disposing. If a callback method is a 
    /// long running process, it may take a while for 
    /// <see cref="System.Threading.Timer.Dispose(WaitHandle)"/> to signal, which is why
    /// it is recommended that the callback method to support cancellation.
    /// </remarks>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Interlocked.Read(ref _disposedCount) > 0)
            return;

        // Wait for timer queue to be emptied, before we continue.
        // Timer threads should have left the callback method given.
        lock (_threadLock)
        {
            if (_timer != null)
                return;

            Stop();

            // When Dispose(waitHandle) completes, it signals the specified waitHandle.
            // This overload of the Dispose method is used to block until it is
            // certain that the _timer has been disposed. The timer is not disposed
            // until all currently queued callbacks have completed.
            var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            if (_timer.Dispose(waitHandle))
            {
                if (!waitHandle.WaitOne(_timeout))
                {
                    throw new TimeoutException($"Timeout waiting for {nameof(NonOverlappingTimer)} to be disposed.");
                }

                waitHandle.Close();   // Only close if Dispose has completed succesfully

                _timer = null;
                _callBack = null;

                Interlocked.Increment(ref _disposedCount);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTimerElaspsed(object state)
    {
        if (Interlocked.Read(ref _disposedCount) > 0)
            return;

        // Ensure that we don't have multiple timers active at the same time.
        // Also prevents System.ObjectDisposedException when using the _timer
        // inside this method.
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(_threadLock))
        {
            try
            {
                if (_timer == null)
                    return;

                // Stop while callBack is running to prevent reentry if action take
                // a while.
                Stop();

                _callBack?.Invoke();

                // Manually restart the timer to run now + _interval.
                Start();
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_threadLock);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the documentation for the constructors, it is important that the specified callback method support cancellation to prevent the `Dispose` method from throwing a `System.TimeoutException`.

I really just want to make sure that I am not missing any potential race conditions, deadlocks, etc. All feedback and/or comments are welcome.

**Edit** 
@Johnbot pointed out a bug in the `Dispose()` method. Below is the updated method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Disposes of the underlying <see cref="Timer"/>. 
/// </summary>  
/// <remarks>
/// Since the callback method specified for a <see cref="Timer"/>  
/// runs on the <see cref="ThreadPool"/>, it is possible for the timer to elapse
/// after this method is called (i.e. a race condition). This method
/// waits for the queued callback to finish before disposing. If a callback method is a 
/// long running process, it may take a while for 
/// <see cref="System.Threading.Timer.Dispose(WaitHandle)"/> to signal, which is why
/// it is recommended that the callback method to support cancellation.
/// </remarks>
public void Dispose()
{
    if (Interlocked.Read(ref _disposedCount) > 0)
        return;

    // Wait for timer queue to be emptied, before we continue.
    // Timer threads should have left the callback method given.
    lock (_threadLock)
    {
        // update
        if (_timer == null)
            return;

        Stop();

        // When Dispose(waitHandle) completes, it signals the specified waitHandle.
        // This overload of the Dispose method is used to block until it is
        // certain that the _timer has been disposed. The timer is not disposed
        // until all currently queued callbacks have completed.
        var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        if (_timer.Dispose(waitHandle))
        {
            if (!waitHandle.WaitOne(_timeout))
            {
                throw new TimeoutException($"Timeout waiting for {nameof(NonOverlappingTimer)} to be disposed.");
            }

            waitHandle.Close();   // Only close if Dispose has completed succesfully

            _timer = null;
            _callBack = null;

            Interlocked.Increment(ref _disposedCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bug in `Dispose`: `if (_timer != null)` should be `if (_timer == null)`.

Comment: I can’t believe I missed that, lol. Thanks for catching it!

Comment: Is there any reason why do you mix the usage of `lock` and `Monitor`?

Comment: @PeterCsala Yes, to avoid lock contention. `lock` always blocks until the resource is available, but `Monitor.TryEnter` only blocks if it successfully acquires a lock on the resource. In other words, if `Monitor.TryEnter` fails, then I know that a lock has already been acquired, so I don't need to block and wait until the resource is available, I just skip that tick of the timer.

Answer (score 2):

This is very interesting. An alternative, more lightweight approach which would not require dealing with concurrency issues, could be like this.

Simply use a wrapper class to wrap the callback.

```
public class Wrapper
{
    TimerCallback _callback;
    int _counter;
    
    public Wrapper(
        TimerCallback callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
    }
    
    public void Worker(object state)
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _counter, 1, 0) == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                _callback(state);
            }
            finally
            {
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _counter, 0, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this

```
var wrapped = 
    new Wrapper(
        _ => Console.WriteLine("Test"));
            
var  timer = 
    new Timer(
        wrapped.Worker,
        null,
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
```